# Logstash filter text into json format

Tags: logstash

this is our stdout **{}** of Logstash:

```
    { 
"_index": "logstash",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "UPUcBnEBHL50VNrwHY-Q",
"_version": 1, 
"_score": null,
"_source": 
{"host": {"name": "xxxxxx"},
"@timestamp": "2020-03-23T06:37:16.915Z",
"data": {"node": "node1","level": "INFO", "timestamp": "2020-03-23T07:37:11,050","thread": "EthScheduler-Workers-3","throwable": "","class": "BlockPropagationManager","message": "Imported #979 / 0 tx / 0 om / 0 (0.0%) gas /(0xcbd404f6cec12eaecb9bed309b953fe5671ee868843807321772369b47756371) in 0.000s."}
}
```

We desire in ELS the "message" text field in "data" object :

```
    "message": "Imported #979 / 0 tx / 0 om / 0 (0.0%) gas / (0xcbd404f6cec12eaecb9bed309b953fe5671ee868843807321772369b47756371) in 0.000s."

in the JSON structured from below:

    {Imported: 979,Tx: 0,Gas: 0 Hash:0xcbd404f6cec12eaecb9bed309b953fe5671ee868843807321772369b47756371,duration: 0,000s}
```

Could you help us solve the problem?
Thanks in advance!
BR

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write custom **grok** patterns for this, matching the various substrings in the *message* field, for example to extract the *Imported* field

```
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "Imported #%{NUMBER:Imported}" }
  }
```